# substitution with eval and repeat the character by grouping string length?

Tags: regex, perl

My input as follow

```
my $s = '<B>Estimated:</B>

The N-terminal of the sequence considered is M (Met).

The estimated half-life is: 30 hours (mammalian reticulocytes, in vitro).
                        >20 hours (yeast, in vivo).
                        >10 hours (Escherichia coli, in vivo).


<B>Instability index:</B>

The instability index (II) is computed to be 31.98
This classifies the protein as stable.';
```

I want to remove the `<B></B>` tags from string and put the underline for bold tags.

I expected output is

```
Estimated:
---------
The N-terminal of the sequence considered is M (Met).

The estimated half-life is: 30 hours (mammalian reticulocytes, in vitro).
                        >20 hours (yeast, in vivo).
                        >10 hours (Escherichia coli, in vivo).


Instability index:
------------------
The instability index (II) is computed to be 31.98
This classifies the protein as stable.
```

For this tried the following regex but I don't know what is the problem there.

```
$s=~s/<B>(.+?)<\/B>/"$1\n";"-" x length($1)/seg; # $1\n in not working
```

In the above regex I don't know how to put this `"$1\n"`? And how to use the continuous statement in substitution separated by `;` or anything else?

How can I fix it?

Comment: Which version of Perl are you using?

Comment: @Zaid The version of perl is `5.14`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `e` modifier returns back just the last-executed statement, so

```
$s=~s/<B>(.+?)<\/B>/"$1\\n";"-" x length($1)/seg;
```

throws away the `"$1\\n"` (which should really be `"$1\n"`)

This works:

```
$s=~s/<B>(.+?)<\/B>/"$1\n" . "-" x length($1)/seg;
```

The reason I was asking about your Perl version was to assess if it was possible to do what is effectively a variable-length lookbehind with [`\K`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html):

```
$s=~s/<B>(.+?)<\/B>\K/ "\n" . "-" x length($1)/seg;
```

`\K` is available for Perl versions 5.10+.

Comment: I forgot about concatenation now I got it.  It is really nice and thank you :)

Comment: @mkHun you're welcome. Do try out the `\K` suggestion in my edit as well; it's cleaner because you don't have to muck around with `$1` in the replacement string more than necessary

Comment: FYI: `\K` is a *variable-length **positive** lookbehind* workaround.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : true, though the context of this problem should make that clear :)